# what is degree of permutation group?

Tags: group-theory, permutations

Is "degree" the same term as "order" of a permutation group?

Comment: See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_group)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When we talk of permutation group we are considering it as set of permutations of a specific set. The cardinality of that set is called the degree. So a subgroup 0f $S_n$ as permutation of 1 to $n$ has degree $n$.